PWA how to cache dynamic data
I am working on a PWA app and I would like to store some pages in cache for offline use.
My website has the following files
    /icon.png
    /css.css
    /index.php //my homepage
    /index.php?id=123 // product
    /index.php?cat=xxx // category

I have already implemented the code for the sw
My current code is
    const cache = 'My-website';
    const staticFiles = [
      '/icon.png',
      '/css.css'
    ];

    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
      e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cache).then(function(cache) {
          return cache.addAll(staticFiles);
        })
      );
    });

    self.addEventListener('activate',  event => {
      event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
    });

    self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch:true}).then(response => {
          return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
      );
    });

I am saving the static files into cache and it works great. Now I have to store also the php files. As they are dynamic, it is my undestanding that I have to put them inside the "fetch", but exactly how ?
I would like the app to first access the internet and use the online data. Cache has to be used only if the device is offline.
Any help?
